# VB.Net Update data from Datatable/Dataset at design time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datatable, dataset, design-time

I have an application with 2 separate forms...

In 1 form, it takes the inputs from user and stores it in a database...
The table, in this case is staffdetails

In the other form, there is a datagridview1... i have set the datasource of this datagridview at design-time

I use a menu to navigate through the forms... if the second form (i.e. the one with the gridview) is already open, it shows the current number of records, say 4...
when i go to the other form and update the table from there, then if i close the form with the gridview and open it again, the updated table values are not shown in the gridview...

The code used in the second form's load event is-

```
Me.Database1DataSet.staffdetails.AcceptChanges()
Me.StaffdetailsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.staffdetails)
```

what can i write to update the records? the `staffdetails.AcceptChanges()` doesn't work, it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the update method of the tableAdapter.
See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details of using a tableAdapter to save to a database.

Comment: says that there is no such method available... when i type UPDATE after the period, i.e. full stop, the intellisense doesn't provide assistance...